# How to stretch a div vertically and horizontally to occupy all the space?

Tags: css

This is a two part question, I believe, with a third and fourth, bonus twist.

1. What am I doing wrong to get the height of the purple set to 100% to be a little bit too high?
2. How can I set the width of the purple so that it goes 100% of the **remaining** space?
3. Is the only way to get rid of the spacing between the yellow and the purple to alter the HTML code by putting everything on the same line?
4. How can I remove the margin that the green border holds between self and the outer component?

[jsfiddle.net/jL8e5/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/jL8e5/1/)

```
div.faqticleList {
  background: #ffdd00;   /* yellow */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
div.faqticlePreview {
  background: #bb88ff;   /* purple */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code in your question?

Comment: @Arbel I tried to post a link to jsFiddle but SO complains about some code... And I was too quick on the submit button.

Comment: You have to post your code, space it so you can post your fiddle. I edited.

Comment: @Cam I'm sorry - I don't follow. Are you saying that I need to copy the code that is at the link to jsFiddle in SO as well? What did you edit?

Comment: You have to include your code in your question in order to add a jsfiddle. Spacing, if you dont add 4 spaces after your code it wont register your code as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your goals. I assumed:

1. Fixed width left
2. Variable width right

http://jsfiddle.net/wXme4/

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

div.faqticleList {
  background: #ffdd00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
div.faqticlePreview {
  background: #bb88ff;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -203px;
  padding-left: 203px;
}

div.container {
  border: solid 1px #007700;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  //overflow: hidden;
  //overflow: auto;
}

div.faqticleList div, div.faqticlePreview div {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

**Script**

```
document.getElementById("faqticleList").innerHTML = "<div>faqticleList</div>";
document.getElementById("faqticlePreview").innerHTML = "<div>faqticlePreview</div>";
```

Comment: **Godlike!** Coorect assumption and correct answer. It's depressing, actually. I've used to be **the dude** to go to when it came to CSS. Then I did something else for almost a year and poof, the savvyness is gone. Now, that I see your solution, I remember the trick with float and negative margin.

Answer (score 2):

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/yRZZc/1/)

Float the left column, and make the right column a regular block element with `overflow: hidden`. That might be the simplest way to do it.

CSS

```
div.faqticleList {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  float: left;
  ...
}
div.faqticlePreview {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  /* width: auto; */
  overflow: hidden;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Much easier than my solution!

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want, but I would recommend you set your height to fixed, or it wont work,

```
div.faqticleList {
   background: #ffdd00;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 30%;
   height: 150px;
}
div.faqticlePreview {
   background: #bb88ff;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 69%;
   height: 100%;
   clear: both;
}

div.container {
  border: solid 1px #007700;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  //overflow: hidden;
  //overflow: auto;
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Not quite. The width is not 30% on the yellow. It's supposed to be fixed. But the purple one is supposed to fill out the rest of the remaining width. Also, the height of 100% is not in effect...

Comment: If you are trying to fix width this, thats easy, I was assuming you were setting this with the idea to create a responsive website.

Comment: The width of the left one is supposed to be fixed. The width of the right one varies with the page width. The same with the height, but in this case, it's always 100%. I don't get it to work, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to dynamically find the width.

```
JS:
 document.getElementById("faqticleList").innerHTML = "faqticleList";
 document.getElementById("faqticlePreview").innerHTML = "faqticlePreview";
 var difWidth = $('.container').width() - 212;
 $('#faqticlePreview').css( "width", difWidth )
```

Then, in your CSS, remove the width from faqticlePreview and float the other div left:

```
div.faqticleList {
  background: #ffdd00;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}
div.faqticlePreview {
  background: #bb88ff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a2Run/

Note: The width you are subtracting needs to be 212.  200px width from the first div, plus 3px of padding on each side of both divs 200+(3x4)=212